# reshaping 2 fields as margins and counting their intersection

Tags: r, reshape

I'm trying to reshape a sales data.frame, which has this structure

```
 categorization_one   gender       created_at       fk_id_customer_info    CONCAT_gender_cat_one  
1      Toys           Feminino     13/11/2013 04:54         1                   ToysFemale
2      Toys          Masculino     13/11/2013 04:54         2                   Toys Male
3 Computers         Masculino      14/11/2013 04:54         2                   Toys Male
```

I want to do like a excel pivot table, with rows the categorization_one field and as columns the values inside the field CONCAT_gender_cat_one. And the values in this table would be the count between the intersection of categorization_one and CONCAT_gender_cat_one.
I'm trying to do this with reshape package with the following code:

```
cast(compras.parte.1,fk_id_customer_info ~ categorization_one, count, margins = TRUE)
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
incorrect number of dimensions
```

**EDIT**, this is the copy/paste of the result from: dput(droplevels(head(compras.parte.1)))

```
structure(list(categorization_one = structure(c(4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 5L), .Label = c("Bebês/Alimentação/Mamadeiras", "Brinquedos/Desenhos e Pintura", 
"Brinquedos/Games e Eletrônicos/Laptops, Tablets e Cia", "Brinquedos/Primeira Infância", 
"Calçados/Sapatilhas"), class = "factor"), gender = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("Feminino", "Masculino", "Masculino/Feminino"
), class = "factor"), created_at = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "13/11/2013 04:54", class = "factor"), fk_id_customer_info = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("2", "3", "5"), class = "factor"), 
    GENDER_PESQUISA = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "não respondeu", class = "factor"), 
    cat_one_gender = structure(c(4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 5L), .Label = c("Bebês/Alimentação/MamadeirasMasculino/Feminino", 
    "Brinquedos/Desenhos e PinturaMasculino", "Brinquedos/Games e Eletrônicos/Laptops, Tablets e CiaMasculino", 
    "Brinquedos/Primeira InfânciaFeminino", "Calçados/SapatilhasFeminino"
    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("categorization_one", "gender", 
"created_at", "fk_id_customer_info", "GENDER_PESQUISA", "cat_one_gender"
), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a `dput()`, that looks like just the `head()`

Comment: @MrFlick oh ok, dput() output all the factors, but it's impossible to print here, because fk_id_customer_info has 100k factors (1 for each customer)

Comment: @user3511563, maybe `dput(droplevels(head(compras.parte.1)))` then?

Comment: @MrFlick I updated my question with Ananda suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, here's your data in a more friendly data.frame form

```
dd<-structure(list(categorization_one = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Computers", 
"Toys"), class = "factor"), gender = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Feminino", 
"Masculino"), class = "factor"), created_at = structure(c(1384336440, 
1384336440, 1384422840), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    fk_id_customer_info = c(1L, 2L, 2L), CONCAT_gender_cat_one = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 2L), .Label = c("Toys Female", "Toys Male"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("categorization_one", 
"gender", "created_at", "fk_id_customer_info", "CONCAT_gender_cat_one"
), row.names = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "data.frame")
```

Then it sounds like you just want a simple table

```
with(dd, table(categorization_one, CONCAT_gender_cat_one))

#                   CONCAT_gender_cat_one
# categorization_one Toys Female Toys Male
#          Computers           0         1
#          Toys                1         1
```

Comment: thanks! but the data I showed is just a sample, the field categorization_one has more than 600 factors. How can I compute dd without the structure and label parameters?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Can you given an example of the output you desire in your question?

Comment: the output is exactly one you showed in your answer. I just think that computing dd is too complex, since you used the labels as inputs (i have more than 600 rows in some fields), so just would like to know how can I go from my data to your output format without computing dd without labels inputs

Comment: I tried your code and I'm getting Error in unique.default(x) : unique() can be applied only to vectors

Comment: `dd` is just a data.frame. You didn't make it easy to copy and paste the data you posted above thanks to the spaces. Your data should already be in a data.fram. It would have been easier if you had posted `dput(head(yourdata))` originally so we could tell the data types of all the columns.

Comment: got it. I didn't know this function. I update my question with the output of dput(head(mydata)). If you could check it, It would be great. Thanks!

Comment: @user3511563 I tried `with(dd, table(categorization_one, cat_one_gender))` with the updated sample data and it worked fine (no errors about `unique`)